# using 'ls' with options and folder and get full path

Tags: linux, unix, path, ls, pwd

i'm using `ls myfolder`

and I've seen `ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/*` which lists files with full path

the question is how do i list files with full path in a folder? (without using `cd` to go inside that folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find PATH_TO_FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\n"
```

Comment: can't use 'find' in that machine!

Comment: what kind of machine is that? embedded one?

Comment: If no `find` is available on that machine proabably something like this might work for you: `for file in ./* ; do echo "$PWD/$file" ; done`

Comment: an asus eee pod (android with no root access) that does not turn on! with only 15 second adb connection. and i need the files inside.
i'm gonna send the list from 'adb shell' to 'adb pull'

Comment: i'm gonna use it like this `adb shell for file in /sdcard/info/* ; do echo "$PWD/$file"; done | tr '\r' ' ' | xargs -n1 adb pull`

parse error near `do' ..

i think that i wrote something wrong! could you please help me?

Comment: I guess you need to quote the command since otherwise keyowrds would get interpreted by the local shell

Comment: Following up on this answer, to get all files (also dotfiles) from a subdirectory called 'back' (but you could enter any directory here) and move them to somewhere else:  find back -maxdepth 1  | grep "/" | awk '{print "mv " $1 " ."}' | bash

Comment: @BertC You can do this with `find` only: `find back -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec mv  {} . \;`

Comment: I know. But I really like awk :-) You can use this construction for every type of output you want to run a command on.

Comment: Ok, just make sure then that nobody puts a file called `foo .; rm -rf . ;.txt` or similar into your backup :) ... (What I'm saying is: the command line you showed is vulnerable against shell code injection via filenames. find -exec is not)  ... ps: I also really like awk :)